# Main differences between XFS, EXT4 and EFS

Tags: filesystems

I'm starting with back end development, coming from the front end world. Those terms: XFS, EXT4, EFS are alien to me. Not so much the names, but the explanations and differences seem rather complicated, and I wonder if it's possible to lower it down to simple terms.

I run ubuntu, and it was installed using EXT4, but many AWS services offer EFS by default, and some servers like MongoDB database server recommends XFS when using with WiredTiger storage engine.

Would it be possible to write just the basic simillitudes and differences?

I've found this [comparison of File Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) for beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say anything about EFS as it's seemingly a virtual network FS.

> Would it be possible to write just the basic similarities and differences?

Speaking of similarities between ext4/XFS:

- Linux filesystems
- Implement POSIX filesystem APIs
- Allow to grow (ext4 can be shrunk as well)
- Have journalling

Speaking of their differences:

- Different disk structures and modes of operation
- XFS sports full online defragmentation
- Different speeds for various operations (Phoronix publishes such comparisons quite often)
- Different in terms of being resilient to crashes and outages/power cuts.
- Different in terms of supporting O_DIRECT

Comment: Thanks, even if it's not complete, it gives me an idea on what things to compare. +1.